# Is html label stopping propagation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

Why when I click inside the box with the black border, the toggle doesn't execute but when I click outside, it does, but not the checkbox?

```js
var checks = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");

for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
  checks[i].addEventListener("click", tog);
};

function tog(e) {
  e.currentTarget.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
ul li {
  background: #3CF;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  margin: 0.25em 0;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: 1.5em;
}
ul li.active {
  background: #6EF;
}
label {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">1
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">2
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">3
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. As I explained in my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33434309/1699979). Due to bubbling in and out of `lable` tag, the `tog` function is called **twice**. Hence `li` tag is receiving two same events one after the other, hence `active` class is added and removed back-to-back, causing this issue.

You can check this in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gvqjbdL1/) with alert.

---

We can have workaround for this to avoid this situation, by using event's [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) property. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gvqjbdL1/1/) which works as you asked.

```js
var checks = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");

for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
  checks[i].addEventListener("click", tog);
};

var i = 0;
function tog(e) {
        if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'label') {
            i++;  //if we remove this then i will never increment
            if(i%2 != 0) {
                i++;  //to bring back to even, so next click should work fine
                return;
            }
        }
  e.currentTarget.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
ul li {
  background: #3CF;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  margin: 0.25em 0;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: 1.5em;
}
ul li.active {
  background: #6EF;
}
label {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">1
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">2
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">3
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can avoid `i` global variable by using IIFE returning function handler or using closure.

Comment: is it possible to avoid the second bubbling?

Comment: As I explained over the answer in comment. https://jsfiddle.net/hvv6ucu8/7/ Even, the event objects passed are same, so I updated my answer with possible workaround, but there is no straightforward way I guess.

Comment: can you extend the fiddle above? I can't see how that would work with more than one label and one `i` variable

Comment: Since the event is triggered back-to-back, and also JS is single threaded. If label triggers onclick, it MUST complete the other one, which will be fired next. So, I'm not holding state of `li` for each, because `i` will be in stable state always. (check comments in code). `i` is just used to check, is it the **second fire** or not.